# preventing ipmi kernel drivers from loading

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, ipmi, modprobe

I'm trying to prevent the ipmi kernel modules from loading on a server with a SuperMicro X8DTG-D motherboard running Ubuntu 14.04. My motivation for doing so is that the modules sometimes seem to take a very long time to unload when I attempt to reboot the machine. My understanding is that putting the following into a file in /etc/modprobe.d and regenerating the RAM disk used on boot  should prevent the listed modules from loading; however, they still appear to be loaded when the machine is booted even though I confirmed that the file containing the below lines is included in the RAM disk:

```
    alias ipmi_si off
    alias ipmi_devintf off
    alias ipmi_msghandler off
```

Any ideas as to how to disable loading of these modules?

Answer (score 6):

I suggest to create a file /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ipmi.conf containing

```
blacklist ipmi_si
blacklist ipmi_devintf
blacklist ipmi_msghandler
```

Comment: Tried this, but it didn't prevent loading of the modules on reboot either (I did regenerate the RAM disk in this case too).

Comment: i know q/a is old but wanted to update it. Guide for rh/centos: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/41278 . You also need to prevent dependency modules trying to access them. You can print them with `cat /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.dep | grep ipmi`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have **ipmitool** package installed, comment your module in

```
/usr/lib/modules-load.d/ipmievd.conf
```